# Python pandas - convert multiple columns to row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this

| id | non-binary | female | male | others |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | False | False |
| 2 | False | True | False | False |
| 3 | False | False | True | False |
| 4 | True | True | True | False |

I want to combine columns into row like this -
If multiple columns have value True, only use the first column that has value True. Eg, for id=4, since the first True is in column "non-binary", then in the new table, set the gender value to non-binary.
How can it be converted to the table below by using Pandas?

| id | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | non-binary |
| 2 | female |
| 3 | male |
| 4 | non-binary |

Comment: `df['gender'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: or `df['gender'] = df.drop(columns='id').idxmax(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `boolean` values are numeric (True == 1, False == 0) you can use `idxmax` to get the index of the maximum value. This interestingly will correspond to the name of the column where the first True appears if you apply this along the column axis.

```py
# set your index to the id column if it is not already
df = df.set_index('id') 

out = df.idxmax(axis='columns').rename('Gender')

print(out)
id
1    non-binary
2        female
3          male
4    non-binary
Name: Gender, dtype: object


# Can use .reset_index() or .to_frame() to convert back to a DataFrame 
#   (depending on what you want to do with your Index)
print(out.reset_index())
   id      Gender
0   1  non-binary
1   2      female
2   3        male
3   4  non-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this.  But it seems in pandas version 1.5.0 there is a new function called [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies):

Try this:

```
pd.from_dummies(df.astype(int))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and got an error message on the row that have multiple True values.   ValueError: Dummy DataFrame contains multi-assignment(s);    I think it only works when there is only one True value in each row.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': df.id})
df2.loc[df['non-binary'].eq(True), 'Gender'] = 'non-binary'
df2.loc[df['non-binary'].eq(False) & df['female'].eq(True), 'Gender'] = 'female'
df2.loc[df['non-binary'].eq(False) & df['male'].eq(True), 'Gender'] = 'male'
df2.loc[df['non-binary'].eq(False) & df['others'].eq(True), 'Gender'] = 'other'

print(df2)
```

Output:

|  | id | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | non-binary |
| 1 | 2 | female |
| 2 | 3 | male |
| 3 | 4 | non-binary |